# How do I get JOIN these tables to get unique product descriptions from a customer?

Tags: sql, database

I have to find all the unique product descriptions of a certain customer "x", for simplicity, has purchased with SQL [Using this DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n21Nj.png). I figure I have to use some joins to accomplish this but its been a real head scratcher. If you have any tips or suggestions that would be awesome

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: looks to me is simple join all tables and group by with Cutomerid, productdescription